# too many formulas, excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have to write the date on which someone leaves,
and I need to count the days he's out,
and when he comes back, I need to count how many days he was out,
I use dates,
lets say 
column A: date of leaving
column B: days of leaving
column C: date of coming

column B: =ISBLANK(C2),B2=DATEDIF(A2,TODAY(),"D",B2=DATEDIF(A2,C2,"D")

the program keeps telling me too many formulas used!!!

any suggestions???

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IF`, and you cannot write more than one `=` in your Formula.
 Write in B2:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),DATEDIF(A2,TODAY(),"D"),DATEDIF(A2,C2,"D"))
```

and drag it down in column B